# What is this thing is exactly called in firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I dont know what is this thing is called but i want to get a refrence of it in android so i want to know what exactly is this thing is called , please check the image down

[image]

im taking about this line above "Quote" , whaat is this line is called and how do i get a databse refrence of it in android and really sorry for that bad handwriting though

right now i want to get refrence of 'Quote" im doing it like this

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes");
```

but how can i get a refrence of that line above"Quote"

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("What should i put here to get that refrence ?");
```

Comment: What is your database location?

Comment: It would be the root node  as in `getReference()`.

Comment: Also asked on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/v88vkh/how_do_i_get_database_refrence_from_the_root/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using realtime database that is called firebase reference url

you can try as:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";



    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(child(dbRef, `users/${userId}`)).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

You can find your Realtime Database URL in the Realtime Database section of the Firebase console.

Depending on the location of the database, the database URL will be in one of the following forms: https:// DATABASE_NAME . firebaseio.com (for databases in us-central1 ) for more details on it you can access the documentation on
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: hey sorry but i forget that im using java , if possible can u share java code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a reference to the root of the database, you can call `getReference` without any value:

```
rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Also see the documentation for [`getReference()` without parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#getReference()), which says:

> `public DatabaseReference getReference ()`
>
> Gets a `DatabaseReference` for the database root node.
>
> Returns: A `DatabaseReference` pointing to the root node.

Comment: hey thanks but now im not getting the data , can you help me with that

Comment: Your question was what to pass to the `getReference()` method to get the root of the database, which is what I answered. I'd love to help more, but it's really hard to help without seeing a [minimal reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. I recommend posting a new question with that, so that others can have a look too.